# How can I create a new TSDX project?

Tags: typescript, initialization, tsdx

I want to create a new TSDX project. According to TSDX [Quick Start](https://tsdx.io/#quick-start) documentation, I type

```
npx tsdx create g2
```

I select `basic`, and I get the following output:

```
~/devlocal npx tsdx create g2

::::::::::: ::::::::  :::::::::  :::    :::
    :+:    :+:    :+: :+:    :+: :+:    :+:
    +:+    +:+        +:+    +:+  +:+  +:+
    +#+    +#++:++#++ +#+    +:+   +#++:+
    +#+           +#+ +#+    +#+  +#+  +#+
    #+#    #+#    #+# #+#    #+# #+#    #+#
    ###     ########  #########  ###    ###

✔ Choose a template · basic
✔ Created g2
✖ Failed to install dependencies
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: yarn add husky tsdx tslib typescript --dev

    at makeError (~/.npm/_npx/86071/lib/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:56:11)
    at handlePromise (~/.npm/_npx/86071/lib/node_modules/tsdx/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ~/.npm/_npx/86071/lib/node_modules/tsdx/dist/index.js:173:9
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

- node version: v14.9.0
- yarn version: 1.22.5
- npx version: 6.13.0
- zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
- macos 10.15.6 (19G73)

Comment: Looks like a network issue, try to run `yarn add husky tsdx tslib typescript --dev` manually, check if it works

Comment: It was probably a network issue. Tried again this morning and `npx tsdx create g2` completed without issues. Thanks!

Comment: ignore the error by doing ctr+C and after that try running npm i or yarn in the project directory.